# What to do when mouse-capturing and keyboard-capturing is unresponsive

Tags: crash, window

When mouse-capturing and keyboard-capturing is unresponsive, I cannot quit the window and I have to wait ~5 minutes for it to automatically stop. Is there a shortcut (which is prioritized to system not window) that quits the program?

Comment: Some context is needed.

Comment: An app captures mouse and all keyboard shortcuts, but when it crashes I have no way to click the “not responding” button or use shortcut to bring up xkill, so I end up waiting.

Comment: Which app? Ubuntu release/version? Under what cirsumstances?